# How I can escape backtick (´) from table name and column name?

Tags: mysql, import, dbimport

I am trying to import DB dump with following command.

```
mysql -u doadmin -p -f tetdb < test.sql
```

then I am getting all imported table name and column warped by  Backtick (´).

´test_cache_menu´
´test_cache_data´

My test.sql is too big (40GB) so I can't edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

use these commands :

1) login to mysql by:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

2) create a database in which you want to import by

```
create database DB_NAME;
```

3) use created database

```
use DB_NAME;
```

4) then export test.sql to your database :

```
source /PATH_TO_DIR/test.sql;
```

that's all

Comment: Not working , table names are still in quotes : ´test_cache_menu´ ´test_cache_data´

Comment: open test.sql in a text editor and verify that is there those tables exist  or not. I think test.sql has only one table exported.

Comment: I can't edit test.sql, its very big ( more than 40GB) and contains 3000 tables. All tables are created properly but the table naming convention is wrong as i explained.

Comment: If it is 40gb data it will takes few hours to execute.